# Why do my feature tests start slowly with Rails, Selenium and Spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, selenium, capybara

I have a Rails 5.0.5 app with feature tests written using Capybara and Selenium (chromedriver).  I am also using spring.  When I run my feature tests, it takes approximately 45 seconds for the first request to my app, then after that, the request times are normal.

I would like to understand why this first request is slow and make it faster - it is a significant problem.

I've set the log level on selenium to debug: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug`

and then I see this:

```
017-10-06 10:40:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9516/session/d61353b6a9b514302b0146b398250ac6/url | {"url":"http://lvh.me:65483/logout"}
2017-10-06 10:40:53 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"36"}
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set `secret_key_base`. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from env_config at /Users/johnnaegle/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246)
```

At this point, its hitting the first URL in my test (/logout) and the browser launched (but hung).  The rails process is running and when it finishes, this shows up in the server logs:

```
[e97dc298-2ac5-4f29-b07c-58b0cc4e8827] Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-06 10:45:16 -0500
[e97dc298-2ac5-4f29-b07c-58b0cc4e8827] Processing by UserSessionsController#destroy as HTML
[e97dc298-2ac5-4f29-b07c-58b0cc4e8827] Redirected to http://lvh.me:53531/login
[e97dc298-2ac5-4f29-b07c-58b0cc4e8827] Completed 302 Found in 834ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[9a296768-7b0a-41f0-9eea-a95414f8a81d] Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-06 10:45:17 -0500
...
[9a296768-7b0a-41f0-9eea-a95414f8a81d] Completed 200 OK in 43621ms (Views: 43571.7ms | ActiveRecord: 21.8ms)
```

I'm on osx.

If I bundle exec a rails console (bypassing spring), eager load my application and exit, that takes 22 seconds.

*How can I figure out why my first feature test takes 45 seconds*?  I thought the point of spring was to make start times and first request times fast, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Nobody owes you a comment with a downvote, they are anonymous by design. Do not call downvoters "cowards" again, this is [completely unwelcome here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: It would be far more useful to indicate what was wrong with the question - it seemed like a reasonable question.  If I could have provided more detail, or asked it in a better way, I would like to know.

Comment: @JohnNaegle Would you be able to contribute to the conversation over here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l  It comes off the back of one of your edits, and it would be interesting to get your take considering it has sparked a huge conversation. Sorry to "@" you on this question - I couldn't do it on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l  (I don't mind your edit, I'd just be interested to see your take)

Comment: @Chris Here is my take, I would contribute to the chat, but its closed now.   I think in isolation, a term like master is not offensive (slave in isolation is always).  But when combined in a context of master/slave -- that is a really charged term and while that terminology is widely used, empathic people must look for and promote alternatives.    WRT to the specific terms whitelist and blacklist vs allowlist and denylist I think there is underlying racial context that associates white with good and black with bad and this is a micro-agression we can try to eliminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara needs to start up its own copy of your app in a separate thread for testing purposes.  That start up time, combined with the first request probably triggering asset compilation (assets are compiled in test mode not in dev mode) is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there anyway to speed that up?

Comment: Other than the things that would normally speed up app startup - remove unused gems, etc - you can precompile the assets in the test env, however that then means always remembering to do that whenever you make a change to them. Additionally, if you're not already using puma as your test server try switching to it `Capybara.server = :puma`